# android using proguard, stack trace?

Tags: debugging, trace, proguard

I tested my app, and in the emulator and on my device it is working without errors.
I export my eclipse-project with proguard option enabled.
The resulting apk is crashing when I open a custom dialog http://code.google.com/p/dateslider/.

I tried the -keep options for all the classes I used, but no result.

From what I have read, is that I need the trace of the crash., to debug.

Where is it?, only a dialog is shown telling me that the app has crashed.

Jos

EDIT

Thanks to Sean's suggestions I narrow it down to a call of the method "SetContentView". It tried to load data from a layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.SliderContainer
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free"
android:id="@+id/dateSliderContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.ScrollLayout
    style="@style/Scroller"
    app:labelerClass="nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.YearLabeler"
    app:labelerFormat="%tY"
    app:childWidth="150dp"/>
<nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.ScrollLayout
    style="@style/Scroller"
    app:labelerClass="nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.MonthLabeler"
    app:labelerFormat="%tB"
    app:childWidth="200dp"/>
<include layout="@layout/dialogbuttons"/>
</nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.SliderContainer>
```

EDIT
The uknown exception is triggered at

```
Class<?> klazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = klazz.getConstructor(String.class);
```

className="nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.YearLabeler".

constructor of YearLabeler:

```
public YearLabeler(String formatString)
```

I tried the folowing proguard options, no succes.

```
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.YearLabeler{
 public <init>(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.MonthLabeler{
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.Labeler{
    public <init>(int, int);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, this was the solution. Thanks Sean for the suggestions.

```
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.YearLabeler
-keepclassmembers class nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.YearLabeler{
 public <init>(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.MonthLabeler
-keepclassmembers class nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.MonthLabeler{
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class * extends nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.Labeler
-keepclassmembers class nl.zonneveld.pldkal_free.Labeler{
    public <init>(int, int);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error -- `ClassNotFoundError`? Meaning, you think Proguard optimized away that class? You can test that easily by setting `-dontshrink`, to start. If that doesn't fix it, Proguard isn't the problem.

You can obtain all log output with `adb logcat` on the command line. There's probably an equivalent for the Eclipse-integrated tools, but I don't know what it is. You can also use the `aLogcat` app on Android to see the logs.

Comment: No error, it just stops with a dialog that it is unexpected stopped.
This is translated from dutch.

Comment: thanks for the aLogCat tip.
The error is: "Thread exiting with a uncaught exception".
This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I narrowed it down to a the method
"SetContentView". It tried to load data from a layout.